# Laravel pivot table with 3 relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to set up my relationship using a pivot table with three different relationships.

```
users
- id
- username

products
- id
- name

tags
- id
- user_id
- name

user_products
- user_id
- tag_id
- product_id
```

When using the "Product" model, I would like to be able to pull all the associated tags.   I'm currently able to pull the "user_products" object, but I would like to know how to pull the actual tag object in stead.

Models:

```
class User {
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserTag');
    }
}

class Product  {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_products','product_id','user_id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        ????
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [eloquent triple pivot](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $this->belongsTo('User','user_products','product_id','user_id')
->withPivot('tag_id')
->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'user_products.tag_id')
->select(...);
```

Something like this should work fine.